# Selenium find_elements By.XPATH trying to extract href urls error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Using the Firefox webdriver, I want to extract all URLs from `a href` that contain a word.
I'm using the latest selenium binary.
Tried this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
nodes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'products')]/@href")
print("nodes: ", nodes)
links = []
for elem in nodes:
    links.append(elem)
```

but get an type error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Attr href="https://www.example.com/catalogue/products/a.html"]
```

Also tried `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'products')]")`
and then using `getAttribute("href")` for each one, but couldn't as well.

Don't understand where's the error and how to solve this.

Extract of the html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul class="level2-megamenu">
      <li>
        <div class="level1-title">
          <a href="https://www.example.com/catalogue/products/a.html">
          <strong style="color:#828282;font-size:>Text</strong>                 
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the `href` attributes using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='products']")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'products')]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: That line (XPATH), unfortunately, returned an error  with no message: `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`  .  The page seems to have fully loaded, though.

Comment: This is already solved, with these two lines: `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
nodes = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'products')]"))`.  The method nomenclature is different.  Maybe you could care to explain why, what's the difference.  Thank you anyway for your help.